# C - strlen("288_882_288"+strlen("288_882_288") /2 = 6?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, strlen

So I'm taking an embedded systems course and we are working with C. 
Its the 2nd week, so we are just refreshing our C code memory.

How did this code prints out the number 6? What happens behind the scenes?

```
int main (void) {
    char msg[] = "288_882_288";
    int my_length = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    my_length = strlen(msg+strlen(msg) /2);

    printf("%d",my_length);//prints 6
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't division take precedence over addition?

Comment: `int my_length = 0xFFFFFFFF;` is simply useless code, because you immediately replace `0xFFFFFFF` with a different value in the next line, BTW.

Comment: @KenWhite: It is useless, but I think OP wanted to make sure to get a different value. Although the value likely overflows an `int` and the compiler might eliminate the initialisation completely, of course.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Olaf: Even then it's a wasted op. It does absolutely nothing when it is immediately replaced by the following assignment. It's a useless assignment. It exhibits no different behavior than `int my_length;`, does it? Even if it overflows?

Comment: @KenWhite: I technically fully agree with you. But see it from a beginner's look who thinks the compiler will generate code for exactly what he writes. Worse it that we don't know what he expects.

Comment: @Olaf: I left the comment to point out to the poster that it was a meaningless assignment. It may help them in the future. That's all. I don't see anything *technically* to agree or disagree with; it's a statement of a fact, AFAIK. I can't see any scenario where it would behave differently than simply `int my_length;` or `int my_length = strlen(...);`, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: @Alexander it's evaluated as `msg + (strlen(msg)/2)` because division has higher precedence

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Oh yeah, I completely overlooked that.

Comment: Its a homework question so yeah, some parts of it are useless.

Answer (score 7):

That is because:

```
strlen(msg) = strlen("288_882_288") = 11
strlen(msg) / 2 = 5 (floor value taken)

msg + strlen(msg) / 2 is the same as msg + 5 == &msg[5]    
strlen(msg+strlen(msg) /2) = strlen(&msg[5]) = strlen("82_288") = 6
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess I forgot that C doesn't concatenate the same way java does.

Comment: Yes. Also note that even in C++ the '+' symbol could mean something else due to operator overloading. In C, the '+' symbol does not mean anything other than addition.

Comment: @user1952500 in C++ it could not mean anything else, as operators can only be overloaded on user-defined types

Comment: @M.M the earlier comment tried to make a relation from a Java string to a string literal in C. In the same spirit I talked about another string library in C++ which appends using a '+' symbol. None of these are directly comparable.

Answer (score 1):

This string literal "288_882_288" (that is used to initialize the array) has size returned by the function strlen equal to 11.

This expression `msg+strlen(msg) /2` yields pointer that points to the element of the string literal (more precisely of the array msg) with index `5` because `11 / 2` is equal to `5`.

Thus the length of the part of the string literal starting from index `5` is equal to `6`.

```
                  6 characters  
                    _____
                   |     |
char msg[] = "288_882_288";
                   ^
                   |
                msg + strlen( msg ) / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the

```
strlen(“288_882_288” + strlen(“288_882_288”) / 2)
```

version, string literal in C is an object of array type. As any other object of array type it decays to pointer type, which is `char *` in this case. Pointer arithmetic can be used with that pointer in the usual way. So, the

```
"288_882_288" + strlen("288_882_288") / 2
```

subexpression produces a `char *` pointer pointing appoximately to the middle of `"288_882_288"` string (position 5). Taking another `strlen` from that position will produce the length of the remaining tail portion of the string, which happens to be 6 in your case.